# Membership Page - Contributions page

Tags: civimember, contribution-page

I am currently attempting to make a membership page. I keep getting this pop-up "you need to enable Separate Membership Payment when online contribution page is configured for bo- Membership y Recurring Contribution" when attempting to check off the different membership types offered. How do I fix this?

Thank You,

Comment: Hi Grace - it helps the community if you come back to answers and either critique them or +1 / Accept them

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much means what it says and you should see a checkbox on the Membership tab to enable this.

Or it may mean that you are trying to offer 'auto renew' for Memberships but are incorrectly trying to achieve this via 'recurring contribution'.

I can't tell without know what your requirements are.